# How to prevent browsers on iOS from resizing images?

Tags: html, ios, mobile, media-queries

I have a very simple website that displays images in a vertical gallery (one image per row) using CSS Grid Layout:

```
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows:minmax(375px, auto);
    row-gap: 450px;
    padding-top: 100px;
  }
    
  .gallery-image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
    
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 3vw;
  }
```

In my HTML I have an alternate, small image that should display when the viewport width is < 1200px:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title>iOS viewport test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>Testing!</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
          <img srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/A-Group-Of-Icebergs.jpg 356w,
                       https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Beijing_national_stadium.jpg/1024px-Beijing_national_stadium.jpg 1024w"
               sizes="(max-width: 1199px) 356px,
                      1024px"
               alt="Just testing.">
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```

The small image displays as expected when resizing a browser window below 1200px on a desktop. When I load it on my iPhone (in either Safari 15.1 or Firefox 40.1; browser viewport width 375px, DPR 2), the larger 1024px image is loaded and shrunk to fit the 375px logical width of the viewport.

## What I've tried

The standard solution seems to be to set the viewport to the size of the display with `<meta name="viewport" content=[...]>`. I'm not sure if this would use the actual display size (750px) or the logical size (375px), but in either case the media query condition in the HTML should match, showing the smaller image. But it doesn't.

I followed a couple of other suggestions I found on blogs and similar SO questions: set `user-scalable` off in the viewport `meta` tag, or set `shrink-to-fit=no`. Both of these tags are said to have no effect in recent versions of Safari, and neither fixed my issue.

My Page Zoom setting in Safari is set to 100%.

Any ideas on what might be going on, and the proper way to fix / account for it?

Answer (score 0):

The first image will show up when width is 356px to 1023px. Otherwise the second image shows up.

```
<div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
          <img srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Beijing_national_stadium.jpg/1024px-Beijing_national_stadium.jpg 1023w,
                       https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/A-Group-Of-Icebergs.jpg 1024w"
               sizes="(max-width: 1199px) 356px,
                       1024px"
               alt="Just testing.">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as written. But changing the srcset part to `<img srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/A-Group-Of-Icebergs.jpg 1023w, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Beijing_national_stadium.jpg/1024px-Beijing_national_stadium.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1199px) 356px, 1024px"` does make it work as intended. Can you explain any more about how this works? According to the Mozilla docs for the srcset property: "The specified width must be a positive, non-zero, integer, and must match the intrinsic width of the referenced image."

Comment: The sizes property determines which image to choose. In this case, I changed the size to 1023w. So that it covers the device sizes from 356 to 1023w and chooses the first image for these devices. if the device size is 1024w, it will pick second image.  You can read the full documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Answer (score 0):

I found the following comment on another SO question:

> The browser will multiply the value from the sizes attribute by the
> device's pixel ratio prior to choosing from the list of widths in the
> srcset attribute.

This explains why the original sizes were not matching the srcset widths. After changing my `img` tags as follows, the correct (smaller) images are loaded in both Safari and Firefox on iOS:

```
<img srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/A-Group-Of-Icebergs.jpg 356w,
             https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Beijing_national_stadium.jpg/1024px-Beijing_national_stadium.jpg 1024w"
     sizes="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 178px,
            (max-width: 1199px) 356px,
            1024px"
     alt="Just testing.">
```